# What/where is the best set of documentation for the .NET implementation of the TIBRV API?

Tags: .net, api, documentation, tibco-rv

I've used the .NET API extensively now, but am hitting some edge cases where examples, experience, and searches are kind of hitting a brick wall. For some reason I can't seem to find good documentation (reference docs or otherwise). Does anyone know where I can get this?

Comment: Reflector seems to be the best route at this point. I don't think the implementation has changed much over the years, and it's not using the standard .NET idioms, such as Dispose(). Not to mention use of deprecated Thread.Suspend().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the best answer is to hunt down the documentation in your organization and use that, or to login to http://power.tibco.com/pubslib/. I also found [documentation](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Tibco-Rv/) for unmanaged C++, which is not quite what I want but did provide some use. There was also a [thread discussing this subject](http://www.tibcommunity.com/thread/6648) which might be useful.